# Use grep to find lines containing a string, but not starting with another string

Tags: regex, grep

I am looking up my session config flags in my PHP .ini settings file.

I use this command to find them:

```
 grep -i "session" php.ini
```

But it returns comments and commented out parameters which start with semicolon ";".

How can I change my command so I still get the lines with "session" in but not the ones that start with a semicolon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
grep -i "session" php.ini | grep -vx ';.*'
```

Should work

-v is 'invert match', so only lines that don't match are displayed

-x is whole line match

Comment: You could also just anchor the `;` at the start of the line with `grep -v '^;'`, then you don't need the `-x` option.

Answer (score 2):

give this a try:

```
grep -i '^session\|^[^;].*session' php.ini
```

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
$ cat file
session
session ; trailing comment
; commented line
      session
; session
bad session
sessions
```

You can `grep` lines with session that has not been commended out like so:

```
$ grep '^[^;]*session' file
session
session ; trailing comment
      session
bad session
sessions
```

If you want to eliminate the lines with sessions with the trailing comments:

```
$ grep '^[^;]*session[^;]*$' file
session
      session
bad session
sessions
```

If you want session to be the first word as opposed to just present in the line:

```
$ grep '^[[:space:]]*session' file
session
session ; trailing comment
      session
sessions
```

And if you want session only vs a sub string match:

```
$ grep '^[[:space:]]*session\>' file
session
session ; trailing comment
      session

(GNU or BSD Grep only that last one...)
```

etc